# Virtual cohomological dimension of mapping class group and braid group of punctured surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, group-cohomology, mapping-class-group, braid-groups

Let $B_{k}(S_{g}),$ $MCG(S_{g};k)$ and $MCG(S_{g}))$ are Braid group, Mapping class group (relative to $k$) and Mapping class group of orientable surface $S_{g}$,  respectively. For $g\geq3,$ we have a short exact sequence
$$1\longrightarrow B_{k}(S_{g})\longrightarrow MCG(S_{g};k)\longrightarrow MCG(S_{g})\longrightarrow 1.$$
This short exact sequence gives the relational between the (virtual) cohomological dimensions:
$$vcd(MCG(S_{g};k))\leq cd(B_{k}(S_{g}))+vcd(MCG(S_{g})).$$ Does the same type of relation exist for punctured orientable surface $S_{g}-\{p_{1},\ldots,p_{n}\}?$